# js call function stored in 2D array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

```
var markerArray = [];//global var
var markerCnt = 0;//global var
for(var x=0;x<10;x++){
    markerArray[markerCnt] = new Array(agency, address, marker, onMarkerClick);
    //agency and agency = string
    //marker = google maps marker
    //onMarkerClick = function
    markerCnt++;
}
```

How do I call a specified onMarkerClick function?
Would I just do:

```
markerArray[0][3]();
```

Comment: Assuming `onMarkerClick` references a function, then yes. You should have tried that before you posted your question :)

Comment: You can make the new array with `[agency, address, marker, onMarkerClick]` instead of `new Array()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is *yes*.

You can execute any function stored in an array, no matter how many dimensions.

```
// perfectly valid
markerArray[0][3]()

// as is this
someArray[0][1][7][2]()
```

To go a little bit beyond than just answering your question, I would suggest using an array of objects so you don't have to execute an array member. This will increase readability of your code and saves you a few hours if you look at it in 6 months trying to figure out what you did.

```
var markerArray = [];//global var
var markerCnt = 0;//global var
for(var x=0;x<10;x++){
    markerArray[markerCnt] = {
        agency: agency
        address: address
        marker: marker
        onMarkerClick: onMarkerClick
    };
    //agency and agency = string
    //marker = google maps marker
    //onMarkerClick = function
    markerCnt++;
}

// then reference your function
markerArray[0].onMarkerClick();
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, you can also do this:

```
var markerArray = [];
var markerCnt = 0;

for(var x=0;x<10;x++){
    markerArray[markerCnt] = {
        'agency' : agency, 
        'address' : address, 
        'marker' : marker, 
        'click' : onMarkerClick
    };
    markerCnt++;
}

//To call the click
markerArray[0].click();
```

Comment: I dont want to click on the marker tho, I already have that functionality, I want to click on a list item outside of the map and have it open a infowindow. I figured it out.

Comment: Are you working with Google Maps API? You should have tagged that in your question. I just finished building a search form that returns a Google Map and markers on the addresses with a listing to the left with the addresses. I'm using the maps api to reverse lookup the lat/lon of the addresses. Clicking the address listing makes the marker bounce. Clicking the marker highlights the corresponding list item and pops up an info window with a link to a detailed information page for the address. It's all AJAX and jQuery and Javascript.